# networkx in python reading from csv file

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a data in csv file and that has following datas in it:

```
    Origin  Destiny  Hours
0     Alat     Baku   1.08
1     Baku     Alat   1.13
2     Alat  Shirvan   0.83
3  Shirvan     Alat   0.80
4  Imishli  Shirvan   1.42
Index(['Origin', 'Destiny', 'Hours'], dtype='object')
```

Now when i do

```
G = networkx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source='Origin', target='Destiny', edge_attr=True)
```

there happens a problem or a misunderstanding for me: Because both `G.edges["Baku","Alat"]` and `G.edges["Alat","Baku"]` gives the same result which is `{'Hours': 1.13}`. Why is it like this,as it should give 1.08 and 1.13 for reversed order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Directed graphs by using parameter `create_using=networkx.DiGraph()`

```python
G = networkx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    data, source='Origin', target='Destiny', edge_attr=True,
create_using=networkx.DiGraph())
```

Comment: It solved the problem. But i did not get what was the problem and why it worked with DiGraph()?

Comment: @SamadzadeMuhammed By default, `from_pandas_edgelist()` uses undirected graph, which can only have one edge between two nodes. Using `Digraph()`, there can be two different edges between two nodes but each edge has different direction.
So in your case, Alat --> Baku and Alat <-- Baku.